# How to use an overridden constant in an inheritanced class

Tags: ruby, class, inheritance, constants

given this code:

```
class A
  CONST = 'A'

  def initialize
    puts CONST
  end
end

class B < A
  CONST = 'B'
end

A.new # => 'A'
B.new # => 'A'
```

I'd like `B` to use the `CONST = 'B'` definition, but I don't know how. Any ideas?

Greetings

Tom

Answer (score 82):

```
class A
  CONST = 'A'

  def initialize
    puts self.class::CONST
  end
end

class B < A
  CONST = 'B'
end

A.new # => 'A'
B.new # => 'B'
```

Comment: So... this means there is no way to do it without changing everywhere in class A that uses CONST?

Comment: Yes. Constant lookup is usually bound at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

I had a few issues with the solution by Konstantin Haase. When accessing the constant in an instantiated object of the inheriting class, the parent constant was used.

I had to explicitly refer to the class.

```
self.class::CONST
```

cheers

Comment: how is this different from his answer?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry I couldn't get the code formatting to work in a 'comment' only in an 'answer' but this is in response to akostadinov's question to Hendrik "how is this different from his [Konstantin's] answer?"

I'd guess Hendrik was trying to access the constant from methods in his inheriting class & that depends on if it's an instance or static method.  It seems to behave as you'd expect in an instance method.  But maybe or maybe not how you'd expect for a static method.  Even if that's not what Hendrik meant, this may be worth noting:

If you have the exact class definitions as Konstantin, but you add a method to class A like this:

```
def self.print_const
  puts CONST
end
```

Then you get A both times:

```
A.print_const # prints A
B.print_const # prints A
```

However if you define the method in A by referencing the class:

```
def self.print_const
  puts self::CONST
end
```

Then you get:

```
A.print_const # prints A
B.print_const # prints B
```

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone finds this and is using module extension instead, just use

`self::CONST`