# Can I use methods instead of constants?

Tags: ruby

Is there any point of using constants instead of methods returning those constants like this?

```
class Foo
  LETTERS = [:a, :b, :c]
  # and them call it Foo::LETTERS
end

# or 
class Foo
  def self.letters
    [:a, :b, :c]
    # and then call it Foo.letters, more simplier
  end
end
```

I could see only one advantage of first approach: warning when trying to redefine constant, but it's rare case, I think.

Comment: The second approach creates a new array each time you call `Foo.letters`...

Comment: @UriAgassi Your comment could be a good answer, I think.

Comment: As per your current context, I think first approach is good, if you don't have in mind to return a different array object in each access to `LETTERS`.

Comment: oh, of course @UriAgassi is right. I forgot such a simple thing :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your second approach creates a new array each time the method `Foo.letters` is called. This, of course, can be fixed by saving the value:

```
class Foo
  def self.letters
    @letters ||= [:a, :b, :c]
  end
end
```

Also, there are some changes in behavior when inheriting such a class with each approach (see "[How to use an overridden constant in an inheritanced class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174563/how-to-use-an-overridden-constant-in-an-inheritanced-class)")

Personally, I don't see how `Foo.letters` is simpler than `Foo::LETTERS` - an extra character? I think that constants should be used for constants, and that static methods have their own use-cases...